If a man is wearing shorts which don't reach the knee, can he fulfill the mitzvah of Sh'ma?
There's plenty of information online on dress during prayer in general.  But it's harder to find information on dress while saying Shma.
My question
Imagine that a man is wearing a pair of shorts.  However, the shorts aren't long enough to reach his knees.
Is it fine for him to say the morning or evening Sh'ma while wearing this pair of shorts, and to thereby fulfill his obligation to say the Sh'ma?
Edit
Based on this source:  It seems to me that the rules of dress for saying Sh'ma are likely the same as the rules of dress for saying b'rachot (blessings).
